# NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //span[contains(text(), 'Distance')]

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have this code, but it fails with the error `NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //span[contains(text(), 'Distance')]`.

This is the [page](https://www.flightmanager.com/content/timedistanceform.aspx) that I use for scraping. For my input data, `distance` should be equal to:

> 261.30 (NM) / 300.76 (MI) / 483.93 (KM)

What is wrong in my code? I checked that all elements are specified correctly.

```
import time
from   selenium import webdriver
from   selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from   selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from   selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
browser.get("https://www.flightmanager.com/content/timedistanceform.aspx")

departure_airport = browser.find_element_by_id("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDepartureICAO")
arrival_airport = browser.find_element_by_id("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtArrivalICAO")
submit   = browser.find_element_by_id("ContentPlaceHolder1_BtnSubmit")

departure_airport.send_keys("LEMD")
arrival_airport.send_keys("LEBL")

submit.click()

delay = 3 # seconds

try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, delay)
    distance = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Distance')]").text
    print(distance)
    time.sleep(10)
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("Scraping failed")
    time.sleep(10)

browser.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a `NoSuchElementException` error because your xpath points to nothing.

What about

```
distance = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
    "//*[contains(text(), 'Distance')]/span[1]"
).text
```

Comment: Ouh, it fails SOMETIMES, but I do not understand why. For example, it fails for origin "LIRF" and destination "LEMD", though there is span class with "Distance" in the response page. Does it happen to you? I added time.sleep(10), but still the same issue.

Comment: @Scala With `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By` and `from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC`, did you try adding `WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Distance')]/span[1]")))` ?

Comment: @Scala For me it worked with the example you gave, i.e. from *LIRF* to *LEMD*. Do you have cases for which it nevers works?

Comment: It was failing randomly without any logic. When I added `WebDriverWait(browser, delay)`, everything stabilised. Thanks. If it fails again, I will open another thread.